Definition of coercive boundary value problems
In Folland's Introduction to PDE,page 242, he defines what it means for a Dirichlet form to be coercive (a standard definition). Let $X$ be a closed subspace of $H_m(\Omega)$ with $H_m^0(\Omega)\subseteq X\subseteq H_m(\Omega)$. $D(v,u)$ is said to be coercive over $X$ if
$$\mathrm{Re}\: D(u,u)\geq C \| u\|^2_{m,\Omega}-\lambda \|u\|_{L^2}^2,\quad \forall u\in X.$$
My question is: why is it important that he took the real part of the form instead of using the weaker assumption:
$$|D(u,u)|\geq C \| u\|^2_{m,\Omega}-\lambda \|u\|_{L^2}^2.$$
I don't see where he used the stronger inequality.

I don't have the book to hand, but the key to coercivity normally is the boundedness from below. Folland's condition implies that the real part of $D(u,u)$ can become a little negative, but not too much. In particular there exists an infimum and any minimizing sequence will be bounded. With your condition that is not the case, as $D(u,u)$ could simply go to $-\infty$.

Thanks, though I don't think Folland finds a minimum like you say. I can see why it would be useful in general, though I'm not sure if it's used in the results he states. For example, is it used in the regularity theory of elliptic boundary value problems?
